# code performance question

Tags: c#, asp.net, performance, large-data-volumes

Let's say I have a relatively large list of an object `MyObjectModel` called `MyBigList`. One of the properties of `MyObjectModel` is an `int` called `ObjectID`. In theory, I think `MyBigList` could reach 15-20MB in size. I also have a table in my database that stores some scalars about this list so that it can be recomposed later.

What is going to be more efficient?

Option A:

```
   List<MyObjectModel> MyBigList = null;

   MyBigList = GetBigList(some parameters);

   int RowID = PutScalarsInDB(MyBigList);
```

Option B:

```
   List<MyObjectModel> MyBigList = null;

   MyBigList = GetBigList(some parameters);

   int TheCount = MyBigList.Count();

   StringBuilder ListOfObjectID = null;

   foreach (MyObjectModel ThisObject in MyBigList)
   {
      ListOfObjectID.Append(ThisObject.ObjectID.ToString());
   }

   int RowID = PutScalarsInDB ( TheCount, ListOfObjectID);
```

In option A I pass `MyBigList` to a function that extracts the scalars from the list, stores these in the DB and returns the row where these entries were made. In option B, I keep `MyBigList` in the page method where I do the extraction of the scalars and I just pass these to the PutScalarsInDB function.

What's the better option, and it could be that yet another is better? I'm concerned about passing around objects this size and **memory usage**.

Comment: For each case, what happens inside the method `PutScalarsInDB`? Are you asking whether or not it makes a difference which method extracts the scalars?

Comment: @both, it creates a row in the DB that stores 1) the string containing the list of ObjectIDs in the list, 2) the number of objects in the list, 3) a string that contains the parameters that were used in the query that produced the list, 4) the userID. Once the row is created, it returns the row.

Comment: As I understand it, both techniques have the same result. The only difference is in where you do the work. If that's the case, then there will be no detectable difference in the runtime. Neither is "more efficient" than the other. How you code it is a style issue, not a runtime performance issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think you'll see a material difference between these two approaches.  From your description, it sounds like you'll be burning the same CPU cycles either way.  The things that matter are:

- Get the list
- Iterate through the list to get the IDs
- Iterate through the list to update the database

The order in which these three activities occur, and whether they occur within a single method or a subroutine, doesn't matter.  All other activities (declaring variables, assigning results, etc.,) are of zero to negligible performance impact.

Other things being equal, your first option may be slightly more performant because you'll only be iterating once, I assume, both extracting IDs and updating the database in a single pass.  But the cost of iteration will likely be very small compared with the cost of updating the database, so it's not a performance difference you're likely to notice.

Having said all that, there are many, many more factors that may impact performance, such as the type of list you're iterating through, the speed of your connection to the database, etc., that could dwarf these other considerations.  It doesn't look like too much code either way.  I'd strongly suggesting building both and testing them.

Then let us know your results!

Comment: ok, I'll add a stopwatch and test timing. What about the consequence in terms of memory? I'm passing an object that's potentially 15MB in size.

Comment: Which object are you referring to?  Passing MyBigList is not an issue -- only one copy of it will exist in memory, no matter how many times you pass it between functions.

Comment: Right, so doesn't making a copy of it adds to memory usage?

Comment: It is only the pointer that gets "passed," not the data itself, so the size of the list will not affect performance.  What *will* affect performance is the size of the string you ultimately commit to the database.  If *that* string is 15MB long, updating the database will be slow.  But again, you have that problem no matter which of the code examples you provided you choose.

Comment: Let me know if my last answer clarified your last question.  Passing an object to a method does *not* make a copy of the object; therefore, it does not have any performance impact.

Comment: The string isn't 15MB long; it's just a list ints in string format. It's the list of objects that could be this size. Thanks for the clarification about passing.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to know which method has more performance you can use the stopwatch class to check the time needed for each method. see here for stopwatch usage: http://www.dotnetperls.com/stopwatch

I think there are other issues for a asp.net application you need to verify:

1. From where do read your list? if you read it from the data base, would it be more efficient to do your work in database within a stored procedure.
2. Where is it stored? Is it only read and destroyed or is it stored in session or application?